# Jest Error Expected: { _id:1} but Received: {_id: "undefined"} while unit testing jwt.helper.js file

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I tried to figure out why the test fails for the jwt.helper.js file. But, unable to find the cause of it.

[file: jwt.helper.js]

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
exports.generateJwtToken = (userObj) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: userObj._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    algorithm: 'HS512',
    expiresIn: '1d',
  });
  return token;
};
```

[file: jwt.helper.test.js]

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { generateJwtToken, verifyJwtToken } = require("../../../helpers/jwt.helper");
jest.mock('jsonwebtoken', () => ({
  sign: jest.fn(),
  verify: jest.fn(),
}));

describe("Unit tests for jwt.helper.js file", () => {
  it('generates a JWT token correctly', () => {
    //Arrange
    const userObj = { id: 1, name: 'testuser', email: 'test@test.com' };
    const jwtSecretKey = 'supersecret';
    const jwtOptions = { option_key1: "option_value1", option_key2: "option_value2" };
    const token = "jsontoken";

    const signSpy = jest.spyOn(jwt, 'sign').mockReturnValue(token);

    //Act
    const result = generateJwtToken(userObj);

    //Assert
    expect(result).toBe(token);
    expect(signSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ _id: userObj.id }, jwtSecretKey, jwtOptions);
  });
});
```

[Output]

```
- Expected
    + Received

      Object {
    -   "_id": 1,
    +   "_id": undefined,
      },
    - "supersecret",
    + undefined,
      Object {
    -   "option_key1": "option_value1",
    -   "option_key2": "option_value2",
    +   "algorithm": "HS512",
    +   "expiresIn": "1d",
      },
```

Number of calls: 1

```
  22 |     //Assert
  23 |     expect(result).toBe(token);
> 24 |     expect(signSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ _id: userObj.id }, jwtSecretKey, jwtOptions);
     |                     ^
  25 |   });
  26 |
  27 |   it('verifies a JWT token correctly', () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/unit/helpers/jwt.helper.test.js:24:21)
```

I wanted to write the test for the **generateJwtToken** function so that it could call the mock version of the jsonwbtoken module. I wanted to make sure that the **sign** function of that module is called with the necessary arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some issues:

1. It's `userObj._id`, not `userObj.id`;
2. Use `jest.spyOn(jwt, 'sign')` is enough, don't need to use `jest.mock('jsonwebtoken')`
3. You didn't set the value for `process.env.JWT_SECRET` environment variable in the test case.
4. The jwt options is `{ algorithm: 'HS512', expiresIn: '1d' }`, not `{ option_key1: "option_value1", option_key2: "option_value2" }`

E.g.

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { generateJwtToken, verifyJwtToken } = require('./jwt.helper');

describe('Unit tests for jwt.helper.js file', () => {
  it('generates a JWT token correctly', () => {
    const originJwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
    //Arrange
    const userObj = { _id: 1, name: 'testuser', email: 'test@test.com' };
    const jwtSecretKey = 'supersecret';
    const token = 'jsontoken';

    process.env.JWT_SECRET = jwtSecretKey;
    const signSpy = jest.spyOn(jwt, 'sign').mockReturnValue(token);

    //Act
    const result = generateJwtToken(userObj);

    //Assert
    expect(result).toBe(token);
    expect(signSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ _id: userObj._id }, jwtSecretKey, {
      algorithm: 'HS512',
      expiresIn: '1d',
    });
    process.env.JWT_SECRET = originJwtSecret;
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77934725/jwt.helper.test.ts
  Unit tests for jwt.helper.js file
    √ generates a JWT token correctly (2 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.842 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Comment: It solved my error. Thanks @Lin Du.

Answer (score 0):

The mock `userObj` variable uses an `id` property whereas `generateJwtToken` expects the argument to have an `_id` property.

Hence when this executes:

```
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: userObj._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    algorithm: 'HS512',
    expiresIn: '1d',
  });
```

`userObj._id` would be undefined.

To fix:

```
describe("Unit tests for jwt.helper.js file", () => {
  it('generates a JWT token correctly', () => {
    //Arrange
    const userObj = { _id: 1, name: 'testuser', email: 'test@test.com' };
    const jwtSecretKey = 'supersecret';
    const jwtOptions = { option_key1: "option_value1", option_key2: "option_value2" };
    const token = "jsontoken";

    const signSpy = jest.spyOn(jwt, 'sign').mockReturnValue(token);

    //Act
    const result = generateJwtToken(userObj);

    //Assert
    expect(result).toBe(token);
    expect(signSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ _id: userObj._id }, jwtSecretKey, jwtOptions);
  });
});
```

There are other differences in the other args. `jwtOptions` is not the same as what is actually used inside of the `generateJwtToken` implementation.

Comment: I did above changes. Still I am getting below error.

Comment: - Expected
    + Received

      {"_id": 1},
    - "super_secret_jwt_token",
    + undefined,
      {"algorithm": "HS512", "expiresIn": "1d"},

    Number of calls: 1

      21 |     //Assert
      22 |     expect(result).toBe(token);
    > 23 |     expect(signSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ _id: userObj._id }, jwtSecretKey, jwtOptions);
         |                     ^
      24 |   });
      25 |
      26 |   it('verifies a JWT token correctly', () => {

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/unit/helpers/jwt.helper.test.js:23:21)